# Backbone.js Collections

Tags: json, backbone.js

I am working with backbone.js. I am trying to send a request to restful service i am getting the resultset as json object as shown

```
{
"Msgs": [
    "Alert",
    "Not"
],
"MessageStatus": [
    "Active",
    "Inactive"
],
"date": {
    "From": "2013-04-25",
    "To": "2013-06-25"
},
"Mlist": {
    "Status": "PND",
    "Role": "Admin,User",
    "To": "2013-06-24",
    "Id": 6,
    "Datecreated": "2013-06-24",
    "Title": "Title5",
    "From": "2013-06-20"
}
}.
```

I am putting the json object extracting and setting it to collection but I am not able to get particular model from the collection with specific id.

Comment: could you please paste a little bit more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your model can be identified with id. You have to set the id in the attributes hash:

```
{
  "id": 1001,
  "Msgs": [
    "Alert",
    "Not"
  ],
  "MessageStatus": [
    "Active",
    "Inactive"
  ],
  "date": {
    "From": "2013-04-25",
    "To": "2013-06-25"
  },
  "Mlist": {
    "Status": "PND",
    "Role": "Admin,User",
    "To": "2013-06-24",
    "Id": 6,
    "Datecreated": "2013-06-24",
    "Title": "Title5",
    "From": "2013-06-20"
   }
}
```

Then using backbone collection "findWhere" method to get the specific id model.

```
//assume msgCollection is which you put the models
var model = msgCollection.findWhere({id: 1001});
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your model and parse your input data. Checkout http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model, http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse and http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse.